# Knockout paging component crashes. Why?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Here is my knockout component that displays a table with some data.
(I have simplified it as much as I could just to be easier to understand it)

It works fine when there are not much rows in the data array, but if there are 1.5 thousand rows or more it freezes if I flip through all the pages and then crashes with "out of memory" error message.

What may cause the error?
Is there a way to fix this?

```
ko.components.register("table-pg", {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        // params
        this.pageSize = +params["pageSize"];
        this.allItems = ko.utils.unwrapObservable( params["values"] );
        this.columns = ko.observableArray( params["columns"] );

        this.totalPagesCount = ko.pureComputed(function () {
            return Math.ceil(this.allItems.length / this.pageSize);
        }, this);

        this.pageNum = ko.observable(0);

        this.items = ko.pureComputed(function () {
            var startIndex = this.pageSize * this.pageNum();
            return this.allItems.slice(startIndex, startIndex + this.pageSize);
        }, this);

        this.gotoNextPage = function () {
            var pn = this.pageNum();
            if (pn < this.totalPagesCount() - 1) this.pageNum(pn + 1);
        }
    },
    template:' \
        <div> \
            <table> \
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: items"> \
                    <tr class="value-item" data-bind="foreach: $component.columns"> \
                        <td data-bind=" \
                            text: ko.pureComputed( function () { \
                                return $parent.property($data).value()  \
                            } ), \
                        "></td> \
                    </tr> \
                </tbody> \
            </table> \
            \
            <a href="#next" data-bind="click: gotoNextPage, text: nextPageTitle"></a> \
        </div> \
        '
});
```

Comment: Can you show what you are passing in params? Not the entire 1.5K items, just a summary.

Comment: @Derpanel params["values"] is an array of very complex objects with properties, methods, sub-objects... I'm not sure if it is possible to paste it here. Moreover I don't know all the subtleties of this object...

It look like memory is not cleared when you click on the "next" button and I wonder why

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the template since you are making to many pureComputeds in each column. if you have 6 columns and 1.5k items, that would make around 9000 functions which is a lot. Try use the ff:

```
<td data-bind="text: $parent.property($data).value()"></td>
```

I think this would be sufficient.